# Magento customer upload images and ask form

Tags: magento-1.8, image, cms

*As the Title says, i need a CMS Page where customers can upload a jpeg/png file to prove that he/she shared a product on facebook/twitter.
The page should have Name and email fields as well.

- Another CMS Page where customers can ask for a specific product, with a message after submit button is pressed that "We will look on your needs bla bla".

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

A CMS page can't really handle forms. You will need to create an extension with a controller that handles the displaying of the forms and handles the incoming post action.

[This post by Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/) tells you more about creating a custom contact form. I would suggest using that as a starting point. And on fileuploading I would suggest [this post on Decryptweb](http://blog.decryptweb.com/file-upload-magento/).

If you're not familiar with building extensions might I suggest this [webforms extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webforms-community-edition.html). I've used it once before and the client was happy with what it could do. It might help you build your forms as well.